# How to implement retry policies while sending data to another application?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, guava, java-failsafe

I am working on my application which sends data to `zeromq`. Below is what my application does:

- I have a class **`SendToZeroMQ`** that send data to zeromq.
- Add same data to **`retryQueue`** in the same class so that it can be retried later on if acknowledgment is not received. It uses guava cache with maximumSize limit.
- Have a separate thread which receives acknowledgement from the zeromq for the data that was sent earlier and if acknowledgement is not received, then **`SendToZeroMQ`** will retry sending that same piece of data. And if acknowledgement is received, then we will remove it from **`retryQueue`** so that it cannot be retried again.

Idea is very simple and I have to make sure my retry policy works fine so that I don't loose my data. This is very rare but in case if we don't receive acknolwedgements.

I am thinking of building two types of **`RetryPolicies`** but I am not able to understand how to build that here corresponding to my program:

- `RetryNTimes:` In this it will retry N times with a particular sleep between each retry and after that, it will drop the record.
- `ExponentialBackoffRetry:` In this it will exponentially keep retrying. We can set some max retry limit and after that it won't retry and will drop the record.

Below is my **`SendToZeroMQ`** class which sends data to zeromq, also retry every 30 seconds from a background thread and start **`ResponsePoller`** runnable which keeps running forever:

```
public class SendToZeroMQ {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
  private final Cache<Long, byte[]> retryQueue =
      CacheBuilder
          .newBuilder()
          .maximumSize(10000000)
          .concurrencyLevel(200)
          .removalListener(
              RemovalListeners.asynchronous(new CustomListener(), executorService)).build();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final SendToZeroMQ INSTANCE = new SendToZeroMQ();
  }

  public static SendToZeroMQ getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SendToZeroMQ() {
    executorService.submit(new ResponsePoller());
    // retry every 30 seconds for now
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for (Entry<Long, byte[]> entry : retryQueue.asMap().entrySet()) {
          sendTo(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public boolean sendTo(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    Optional<ZMQSocketInfo> liveSockets = PoolManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
    if (!liveSockets.isPresent()) {
      return false;
    }
    return sendTo(address, encodedRecords, liveSockets.get().getSocket());
  }

  public boolean sendTo(final long address, final byte[] encodedByteArray, final Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(encodedByteArray);
    boolean sent = msg.send(socket);
    msg.destroy();
    // adding to retry queue
    retryQueue.put(address, encodedByteArray);
    return sent;
  }

  public void removeFromRetryQueue(final long address) {
    retryQueue.invalidate(address);
  }
}
```

Below is my **`ResponsePoller`** class which polls all the acknowledgement from the zeromq. And if we get an acknowledgement back from the zeromq then we will remove that record from the retry queue so that it doesn't get retried otherwise it will get retried.

```
public class ResponsePoller implements Runnable {
  private static final Random random = new Random();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
    Socket client = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.PULL);
    String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
    client.setIdentity(identity.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));
    client.bind("tcp://" + TestUtils.getIpaddress() + ":8076");

    PollItem[] items = new PollItem[] {new PollItem(client, Poller.POLLIN)};

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      // Tick once per second, pulling in arriving messages
      for (int centitick = 0; centitick < 100; centitick++) {
        ZMQ.poll(items, 10);
        if (items[0].isReadable()) {
          ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client);
          Iterator<ZFrame> it = msg.iterator();
          while (it.hasNext()) {
            ZFrame frame = it.next();
            try {
                long address = TestUtils.getAddress(frame.getData());
                // remove from retry queue since we got the acknowledgment for this record
                SendToZeroMQ.getInstance().removeFromRetryQueue(address);               
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // log error
            } finally {
              frame.destroy();
            }
          }
          msg.destroy();
        }
      }
    }
    ctx.destroy();
  }
}
```

---

**Question:**

As you can see above, I am sending `encodedRecords` to zeromq using **`SendToZeroMQ`** class and then it gets retried every 30 seconds depending on whether we got an acknolwedgement back from `ResponsePoller` class or not.

For each `encodedRecords` there is a unique key called `address` and that's what we will get back from zeromq as an acknowledgement.

How can I go ahead and extend this example to build two retry policies that I mentioned above and then I can pick what retry policy I want to use while sending data. I came up with below interface but then I am not able understand how should I move forward to implement those retry policies and use it in my above code.

```
public interface RetryPolicy {
    /**
     * Called when an operation has failed for some reason. This method should return
     * true to make another attempt.
     */
    public boolean allowRetry(int retryCount, long elapsedTimeMs);
}
```

Can I use [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) or [failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) here becuase these libraries already have many retry policies which I can use?

Comment: A similar problem is solved by spring-retry project. The decision whether to retry, and how long to back off are decoupled though. You might want to take a look there for comparison.

Comment: just wondering, why aren't you using an enterprise integration framework like Camel or Mule? Then you get all the messaging and "retries" stuff for free.

Answer (score 5):

I am not able to work out all the details regarding how to use the relevant API-s, but as for algorithm, you could try:

- the retry-policy needs to have some sort of state attached to each message (atleast the number of times the current message has been retried, possible what the current delay is). You need to decide whether the RetryPolicy should keep that itself or if you want to store it inside the message.
- instead of allowRetry, you could have a method calculating when the next retry should occur (in absolute time or as a number of milliseconds in the future), which will be a function of the state mentioned above
- the retry queue should contain information on when each message should be retried.
- instead of using `scheduleAtFixedRate`, find the message in the retry queue which has the lowest `when_is_next_retry` (possibly by sorting on absolute retry-timestamp and picking the first), and let the executorService reschedule itself using `schedule` and the `time_to_next_retry`
- for each retry, pull it from the retry queue, send the message, use the RetryPolicy for calculating when the next retry should be (if it is to be retried) and insert back into the retry queue with a new value for `when_is_next_retry` (if the RetryPolicy returns -1, it could mean that the message shall not be retried any more)

Comment: Thanks for  proposing an algorithm here. I am mainly having difficulties implementing this as well. I had some idea before but I was struggling to implement it efficiently in a right way. If you are having difficulty understanding API's I am using, then let me know, I can improve my question accordingly. Idea is very simple though, I am sending `encodedRecords` to zeromq and zeromq will give an acknowledgement back with a long address and I will remove this long address from the retryqueue  so that it doesn't get retried again.

Comment: I don't have any experience programming for neither zeromq nor `ScheduledExecutorService`, so my suggestions are based on an abstract understanding of the problem. I understand your basic question and your requirement to vary the retry-algorithm. My main suggestion is that your `RetryPolicy` returns **when** a message should be retried (as number-of-mlliseconds-from-now or an absolute timestamp), instead of returning a boolean. I am afraid I can't help you with more details unless you show me what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

not a perfect way, but can be achieved by below way as well.

```
public interface RetryPolicy {
public boolean allowRetry();
public void decreaseRetryCount();
```

}

Create two implementation. For RetryNTimes

```
public class RetryNTimes implements RetryPolicy {

private int maxRetryCount;
public RetryNTimes(int maxRetryCount) {
    this.maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount;
}

public boolean allowRetry() {
    return maxRetryCount > 0;
}

public void decreaseRetryCount()
{
    maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount-1;
}}
```

---

For ExponentialBackoffRetry

```
public class ExponentialBackoffRetry implements RetryPolicy {

private int maxRetryCount;
private final Date retryUpto;

public ExponentialBackoffRetry(int maxRetryCount, Date retryUpto) {
    this.maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount;
    this.retryUpto = retryUpto;
}

public boolean allowRetry() {
    Date date = new Date();
    if(maxRetryCount <= 0 || date.compareTo(retryUpto)>=0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void decreaseRetryCount() {
    maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount-1;
}}
```

You need to make some changes in SendToZeroMQ class

```
public class SendToZeroMQ {

private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
private final Cache<Long,RetryMessage> retryQueue =
        CacheBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10000000)
                .concurrencyLevel(200)
                .removalListener(
                        RemovalListeners.asynchronous(new CustomListener(), executorService)).build();

private static class Holder {
    private static final SendToZeroMQ INSTANCE = new SendToZeroMQ();
}

public static SendToZeroMQ getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
}

private SendToZeroMQ() {
    executorService.submit(new ResponsePoller());
    // retry every 30 seconds for now
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Map.Entry<Long, RetryMessage> entry : retryQueue.asMap().entrySet()) {
                RetryMessage retryMessage = entry.getValue();
                if(retryMessage.getRetryPolicy().allowRetry())
                {
                    retryMessage.getRetryPolicy().decreaseRetryCount();
                    entry.setValue(retryMessage);
                    sendTo(entry.getKey(), retryMessage.getMessage(),retryMessage);

                }else
                {
                    retryQueue.asMap().remove(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}



public boolean sendTo(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords, RetryMessage retryMessage) {
    Optional<ZMQSocketInfo> liveSockets = PoolManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
    if (!liveSockets.isPresent()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(null==retryMessage)
    {
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryNTimes(10);
        retryMessage = new RetryMessage(retryPolicy,encodedRecords);
        retryQueue.asMap().put(address,retryMessage);
    }
    return sendTo(address, encodedRecords, liveSockets.get().getSocket());
}

public boolean sendTo(final long address, final byte[] encodedByteArray, final ZMQ.Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(encodedByteArray);
    boolean sent = msg.send(socket);
    msg.destroy();
    return sent;
}

public void removeFromRetryQueue(final long address) {
    retryQueue.invalidate(address);
}}
```

Comment: In the `sendTo` method, it is taking one extra `RetryMessage` as a parameter. What will this parameter `RetryMessage retryMessage` will look like when I will call `sendTo` method for sending new record for the first time?

Comment: You are calling sendTo method from two places, one for fresh data and another for retry. So for fresh data pass null "sentTo(address,data,null)",

Comment: Yeah I got that figured out after posting my comment. Also I was doing some research and I saw there are two libraries [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) or [failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) have both the retry policies that I am trying to implement. Do you think this will be simpler to integrate in my code.

Comment: I have never used these, need to check. But I think make it simple and use your own implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working little simulation of your environment that shows how this can be done. Note the Guava cache is the wrong data structure here, since you aren't interested in eviction (I think). So I'm using a concurrent hashmap:

```
package experimental;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

class Experimental {
  /** Return the desired backoff delay in millis for the given retry number, which is 1-based. */
  interface RetryStrategy {
    long getDelayMs(int retry);
  }

  enum ConstantBackoff implements RetryStrategy {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public long getDelayMs(int retry) {
      return 1000L;
    }
  }

  enum ExponentialBackoff implements RetryStrategy {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public long getDelayMs(int retry) {
      return 100 + (1L << retry);
    }
  }

  static class Sender {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    private final ConcurrentMap<Long, Retrier> pending = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /** Send the given data with given address on the given socket. */
    void sendTo(long addr, byte[] data, int socket) {
      System.err.println("Sending " + Arrays.toString(data) + "@" + addr + " on " + socket);
    }

    private class Retrier implements Runnable {
      private final RetryStrategy retryStrategy;
      private final long addr;
      private final byte[] data;
      private final int socket;
      private int retry;
      private Future<?> future; 

      Retrier(RetryStrategy retryStrategy, long addr, byte[] data, int socket) {
        this.retryStrategy = retryStrategy;
        this.addr = addr;
        this.data = data;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.retry = 0;
      }

      synchronized void start() {
        if (future == null) {
          future = executorService.submit(this);
          pending.put(addr, this);
        }
      }

      synchronized void cancel() {
        if (future != null) {
          future.cancel(true);
          future = null;
        }
      }

      private synchronized void reschedule() {
        if (future != null) {
          future = executorService.schedule(this, retryStrategy.getDelayMs(++retry), MILLISECONDS);
        }
      }

      @Override
      synchronized public void run() {
        sendTo(addr, data, socket);
        reschedule();
      }
    }

    long getVerifiedAddr() {
      System.err.println("Pending messages: " + pending.size());
      Iterator<Long> i = pending.keySet().iterator();
      long addr = i.hasNext() ? i.next() : 0;
      return addr;
    }

    class CancellationPoller implements Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
          long addr = getVerifiedAddr();
          if (addr == 0) {
            continue;
          }
          System.err.println("Verified message (to be cancelled) " + addr);
          Retrier retrier = pending.remove(addr);
          if (retrier != null) {
            retrier.cancel();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    Sender initialize() {
      executorService.submit(new CancellationPoller());
      return this;
    }

    void sendWithRetriesTo(RetryStrategy retryStrategy, long addr, byte[] data, int socket) {
      new Retrier(retryStrategy, addr, data, socket).start();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sender sender = new Sender().initialize();
    for (long i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      sender.sendWithRetriesTo(ConstantBackoff.INSTANCE, i, null, 42);
    }
    for (long i = -1; i >= -10; i--) {
      sender.sendWithRetriesTo(ExponentialBackoff.INSTANCE, i, null, 37);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using `Guava Cache` because le't say if the retry events keeps increasing for whatever reason and if it  reaches particular limit, then I should drop those records instead of going out of memory. Let me go through your suggestion and try to understand it.

Comment: I guess there is one typo? this line `Sender sender = new Sender().initialize();` should be just `new Sender().initialize();` right? As initialize is  just a void.. But then we are using same sender object below.

Comment: Sorry. `Sender.initialize` should return `this`.  Fixed.  Also it's better if rescheduled sends are done outside `synchronized`.  Fixed that, too. If you do want eviction, then it's easy enough to switch back to `Cache`.  I don't have that library, so the map was a lot simpler to use when developing this example.

Comment: @david Also fixed the constant retry strategy.  The one I had was actually geometric.  Sorry... Didn't have much time...

Comment: Thanks Gene.. Looking into your solution. I think I will have some follow up question later on to understand few things.. Will let you know.. But so far it is making sense to me..

Comment: @david Fixed a race condition. Should be okay now.  But if you have a Guava class that does what you need, you should seriously consider using it. It will be well-tested and supported. Multithreaded stuff is hard to get right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/). It provides a component for zeromq, and tools like errohandler, redeliverypolicy, deadletter channel and such things are natively provided.